# STM32H7xx toggle IO as fast as possible

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I'm trying to toggle an IO on an STM32H743 as fast as possible. I'm using an external 10MHz clock, powered at 3.3V, and I'm confident my main clock is running at 400MHz and the bus clock that talks to the GPIO (AHB4) is running at 200MHz. Here is some sample code I'm using to configure the chip and toggle the IO:

```
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef clock;
RCC_OscInitTypeDef osc;

MODIFY_REG(PWR->CR3, PWR_CR3_SCUEN, 0);
__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
while (!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
// External 10.000MHz oscillator
osc.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
osc.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
osc.HSIState = RCC_HSI_OFF;
osc.CSIState = RCC_CSI_OFF;
osc.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
osc.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
// ((10 / 5) * 400 ) / 2 = 400
osc.PLL.PLLM = 5;
osc.PLL.PLLN = 400;
osc.PLL.PLLP = 2;
osc.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
osc.PLL.PLLRGE    = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&osc);

// Sysclk source is PLL
clock.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK  | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK  |
                   RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 |
                   RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2   | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1);

clock.SYSCLKSource   = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
clock.SYSCLKDivider  = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
// HCLK = SYSCLK / 2 = 200
clock.AHBCLKDivider  = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
clock.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;  
clock.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV2; 
clock.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV2; 
clock.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2; 
HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&clock, FLASH_LATENCY_4);
__HAL_RCC_CSI_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();
HAL_EnableCompensationCell();

// GPIOC0 is pin I'm toggling
__HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
gpio.Mode  = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
gpio.Pull  = GPIO_NOPULL;
gpio.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
gpio.Pin   = GPIO_PIN_0;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);

// Configure GPIOC9 as SYSCLK/2 (200MHz)
gpio.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
gpio.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_MCO;
gpio.Pull      = GPIO_NOPULL;
gpio.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
gpio.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_9;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);    
HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO2, RCC_MCO2SOURCE_SYSCLK, RCC_MCODIV_2);

while (1)
{
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
    GPIOC->ODR = 0;
    GPIOC->ODR = 1;
}
```

When I look at this on an oscilloscope I see my SYSCLK/2 correctly at 200MHz but the toggle pin is only toggling once every 60nS.

[image: scope]

When I look at the disassembly for this code (compiled "-O3"), the toggling is being compiled in to single STR instructions (r1 = 0, r2 = 1, r3 = &GPIOC->ODR):

```
...
str r1, [r3, #20] 
str r2, [r3, #20] 
str r1, [r3, #20] 
str r2, [r3, #20] 
str r1, [r3, #20] 
str r2, [r3, #20] 
str r1, [r3, #20] 
str r2, [r3, #20] 
str r1, [r3, #20] 
str r2, [r3, #20] 
str r1, [r3, #20]
...
```

I can't find cycle information for the Cortex-M7 processor, but when I look at the cycle time for the Cortex-M4 processor (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/DDI0439B_cortex_m4_r0p0_trm.pdf) table 3-1, I see a STR should take two clock cycles to execute. I would expect to see my IO toggling aproimately every 10 nanoseconds (or every two clock cycles on the 200MHz AHB4 bus).

I've tried running the code from FLASH and SRAM, but there is no difference in IO speed.

Why isn't my IO toggling every two clock cycles?

EDIT:

In the reference manual (st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099.pdf) section 10.2 it says, "Fast toggle capable of changing every two clock cycles."

EDIT:

So some comments have mentioned that the processor isn't really meant to talk directly to GPIO. So I've rewritten the code to use DMA (I had to use BDMA and specifically allocate the data in RAM_D3 to get it to run as fast as the software loop). Ultimately I want to clock out calculated data from RAM to the entire GPIO port. How can I clock data out every two clock cycles as the reference manual suggests?

DMA code that runs on a NUCLEO-H743ZI:

```
#include <stm32h7xx_hal.h>
#include <stdint.h>

DMA_HandleTypeDef dma;

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
}

static void ClockConfig(void)
{
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef clock;
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef osc;  
    MODIFY_REG(PWR->CR3, PWR_CR3_SCUEN, 0);
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
    while (!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

    osc.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_CSI;
    osc.CSIState = RCC_CSI_ON;
    osc.CSICalibrationValue = 16;
    osc.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    osc.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_CSI;
    osc.PLL.PLLM = 1;
    osc.PLL.PLLN = 200;
    osc.PLL.PLLP = 2;
    osc.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
    osc.PLL.PLLR = 2;
    osc.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_2;
    osc.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
    osc.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
    HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&osc);

    clock.ClockType      = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2  | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1);
    clock.SYSCLKSource   = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    clock.SYSCLKDivider  = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    clock.AHBCLKDivider  = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    clock.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;  
    clock.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV2; 
    clock.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV2; 
    clock.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2; 
    HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&clock, FLASH_LATENCY_4);
    __HAL_RCC_CSI_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_EnableCompensationCell();

    HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);
    HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

void GpioConfig(void)
{
    __GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
    gpio.Pin   = GPIO_PIN_0;
    gpio.Mode  = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpio.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    gpio.Pull  = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
    gpio.Pin   = GPIO_PIN_1;
    gpio.Mode  = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpio.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    gpio.Pull  = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
    gpio.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    gpio.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_MCO;
    gpio.Pull      = GPIO_NOPULL;
    gpio.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    gpio.Pin       = GPIO_PIN_9;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);    
    HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO2, RCC_MCO2SOURCE_SYSCLK, RCC_MCODIV_2);
}

uint8_t complete = 0;
void DmaComplete(DMA_HandleTypeDef *handle)
{
    complete = 1;
}

void DmaError(DMA_HandleTypeDef *handle)
{
    complete = 1;
}

void DmaConfig(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_BDMA_CLK_ENABLE();
    dma.Instance                 = BDMA_Channel0;
    dma.Init.Request             = DMA_REQUEST_MEM2MEM;
    dma.Init.Direction           = DMA_MEMORY_TO_MEMORY;
    dma.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_ENABLE;
    dma.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_DISABLE;
    dma.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    dma.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    dma.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
    dma.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&dma);
    HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(&dma, HAL_DMA_XFER_CPLT_CB_ID,  DmaComplete);
    HAL_DMA_RegisterCallback(&dma, HAL_DMA_XFER_ERROR_CB_ID, DmaError);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(BDMA_Channel0_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(BDMA_Channel0_IRQn);
}

void BDMA_Channel0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&dma);
}

void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __NOP();
}

__attribute__((section(".ram_d3")))
static uint16_t src[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    ClockConfig();
    GpioConfig();
    DmaConfig();
    while (1)
    {
        complete = 0;
        HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&dma, (uint32_t)&src, (uint32_t)&GPIOC->ODR, 10);
        while (complete == 0) ;
    }
}
```

[image: scope2]

Comment: pipelined processors are not deterministic in general.  if you are running this out of flash you have added problems, some stm32s have a cache you cant turn off, which generally covers the additional clocks that come from running from flash.  you can try running this code from sram to see if that helps.  the m7 also has an icache so you can help there too.

Comment: at the end of the day though this is not how you want to wiggle I/O lines quickly.  there are various peripherals that they offer (not all chips have all the peripherals) that you can control the bit patterns and the clock rate up to what the peripheral can handle.

Comment: before trying to toggle I/O   try a simple test loop  test: sub r0,#1 ; bne test.  try it at both alignments as that can affect performance on this platform.  try it in flash and in ram.  from flash try it at the clock/flash wait state boundaries if any  If say 100mhz is a boundary where the flash wait state changes, try 100mhz at both wait state values.  try it at various core clock speeds.  repeat with nops.  find the fasted place to run the code THEN make the code talk to a peripheral.

Comment: 1) Ths Cortex-M4 can't be used as reference for the M7. They have very different architectures, (internally and externally). 2) Read the TRM (why not the CM7, btw??) **carefully**. the cycles for `STR` expect a loss-less bus. Of course you have to add additional bus-cycles for synchronisation and waitstates, etc.

Comment: I've tried running out of SRAM and the output is the same. Additionally, I tried the same code on an STM32**F7** (which is also a Cortex-M7) dev kit I have, but with the processor at 200MHz, instead of 400MHz. My IO on the F7 toggles at 50Mhz (2*5nS clock cycles) which is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: This guy, https://metebalci.com/blog/stm32h7-gpio-toggling/, saw 'slow' GPIO on the H7.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are wrong. The GPIO speed is not determined by the core instructions timings, but by the physical characteristics of the peripheral. See the table in the DS where static and dynamic GPIO port characteristics are. The maximum speed depends on many parameters.

Comment: Looking through the spec (https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32h743vi.pdf), table 61 says the maximum IO speed for the highest speed (SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH) is 100MHz even with the highest capacitance -- I have no capacitance on the output. In the reference manual (https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099.pdf) section 10.2 it says, "Fast toggle capable of changing every two clock cycles."

Comment: Did you set the compensation cell?

Comment: Yes, the compensation cell is enabled.

Comment: I do not see it in your config.

Comment: Line 38: `HAL_EnableCompensationCell();`

Comment: You always have capacitance on the output. The scope probe has capacitance.